# Ionic 2 - Populating segments dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-directive, ionic2

I have categories and dishes. Each dish belongs to a particular type of category.

I'm making an http request to return all the dishes that belong to a particular type of category. So I'm getting an array with

```
{
  Soup[{'Name','Description', 'Price'..}, ..], 
  Chicken[{'Name','Description',..}], ...
}
```

which contains all soups similarly I have all the chickens in one Array. Now I have created the segments dynamically for every category using:

```
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="relationship" color="primary">
    <ion-segment-button  *ngFor ="let category of categories" value="{{category.Name}}">
  {{category.Name}} ({{category.Listings}})
    </ion-segment-button> 
</ion-segment>
```

Now the part that I'm struggling with is how to populate these segments based on the type of category. So the soup segment will have all the soups. The chicken segment will have all the chickens and so forth.

What I have so far is:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="relationship" *ngFor = "let category of categories"> 
  <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="category.Name" ngSelected="selected">
    <ion-item *ngFor = "let dish of Dishes">
      <h2> {{dish.Name}}</h2>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</div>
```

What I  want to do is to somehow traverse the Dishes array with respect to category and get every `dish.Name` that belongs to that particular category.

Right now I have defined Dishes as `data.data.Soup` so all segments are populated with just the soups.

Comment: So Dishes is a different array from your Categories? It's not nested inside Categories?

Comment: Yes. Categories is a different array. It has three elements, id, name and Listings which is essentially the number of dishes that are inside the category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Mr.Gabriel's comment I realized I was going about it the wrong way entirely! I went back and nested all the dishes that belonged to a particular category in the same array and accessed them by:

```
    <div  [ngSwitch]="relationship" *ngFor = "let category of categories">

    <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="category.Name" ngSelected="selected">

    <ion-item *ngFor = "let dish of category.Dishes">
    <h2> {{dish.Name}}</h2>
  </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
   </div>
```

Comment: Was just about to comment about nesting the dishes in categories. Since it's a JSON there is no problem and it's lightweight. Glad you solved it.